# error while downloading web-app_4_0.xsd in dynamic web app eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

when I try to make maven dynamic web project in eclipse this error occurred

> Error while downloading 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd' to C:\Users\akalanka.lemminx\cache\http\xmlns.jcp.org\xml\ns\javaee\web-app_4_0.xsd.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
```

Comment: Maybe you missed to upgrade facing an already fixed issue: https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/issues/419

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem with each XML files in my Eclipse. In my case this is caused because I use an enterprise proxy and an "older" version of Eclipse (2019). That put a lot of "red cross errors" on all of my projects folders but that will not avoid it to work. I think you can fix it by configuring "Network Connections" in a newer version.

Comment: I am using Eclipse 2021-12 version, and encountered errors related to web-app_4_0.xsd in web.xml file. I checked for pending update of Eclipse by going to the Eclipse installer, clicking on the hamburger sign in the top right, and then clicking on 'Update'. Upon restarting Eclipse IDE, the issue was resolved! No red flags anymore, and I could see the output that my servlet worked upon.